# SNAT does not change source ip

Tags: linux, routes, iptables

I am trying to nat an internal virtual network (adapter tun0 ip: 10.8.0.x - my vpn network) to the outer world (adapter venet0:0 ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

I am using the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0:0 -j SNAT --to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

For some reason iptables is not changing the outbound ip address:

```
tcpdump
08:23:17.863971 IP 10.8.0.6 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3887, seq 1264, length 64

netstat-nat
Proto NATed Address                  Destination Address            State
udp   10.8.0.6:61339                 google-public-dns-a.goo:domain UNREPLIED
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

(ip_forward is activated!)

Comment: It is working now, no clue why ...

Answer (score 0):

check your `iptables -t nat -nvL` very carefully. Maybe  there's a hidden `MASQUERADE` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

have a close look at the selectors, source(-s) and destination(-d). In my case my destination IP was different by one octet. I was expecting .5 and the traffic was destined to .6. like the rule was to SNAT ip `xxx.xxx.5.xxx` and the destination in the packets were `xxx.xxx.6.xxx`